# AMP carousel direction change

Tags: html, amp-html

I need to change default carousel direction *left - right* to *Top - Bottom* Direction.

https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/image_galleries_with_amp-carousel/source/

is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the `amp-carousel` component currently only supports displaying and navigating the slides in x-direction.

Alternatively you could try to use CSS Scroll Snap for your use case instead. See some examples [over at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type#CSS_Content). Though keep in mind that [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-snappoints) is a bit wonky.